# Is there a way to pass variables in Vuejs router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a reusable component that only needs a different api call depending on the component everytime it's called.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/books',
    component: () => import('./Pages/Book-highlights/Nav/index.js'),
    props: {api: '/api/allBooks'}
  }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})
```

As I understand it, the `props` is just to enable the use of URL slugs (or whatever they are called) `?api=something`. I want to be able to do something like this

```
<Nav api='/api/allBooks'></Nav>
```

But of course, buy passing that `api` in the `VueRouter`

Everything I have researched tells me it can't be done but I feel like I have seen it somewhere!

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I've seen that but I don't think that what I need. That simply uses router params, I need to pass my own params without touching the route (without relying on query strings)

Comment: Well, it's hard to understand what you are looking for here. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir in the example you provide, the `id` comes from the URL `/:id` I need to provide that `id` without replying on the url

Comment: Why you need to pass them with the router then? just have them on the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use do this in different ways.
1 Passing parameter through router and working on the necessary configurations based on the parameter. https://codeburst.io/passing-props-to-vue-js-route-components-with-vue-router-e9ad99d8a133
2 if you are calling it as a component in the application, then you could pass in parameters as what you have mentioned above and similarly accept the parameter within the component and work on the necessary changes based on the input value
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-props-to-pass-data-to-child-components/
Let me know if you have any questions